# Update from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that I need to update with data from another table.  Problem is there is no foreign key relationship between the two tables.  However, there is a third table that has the relationship.

Here are the tables:

Parent table:

```
ParentKey     ParentField
-------------------
 p1           aaa
 p2           bbb
 p3           ccc
```

Child table:

```
ChildKey     ChildField
-------------------
 c1           ccc
 c2        
 c3
```

Relationship table:

```
ParentKey    ChildKey
-------------------
 p1          c2
 p2          c3
 p3          c1
```

Here's what I want to do... If the Child table does not have a value in ChildField then I want to update the ChildField with the value of the corresponding ParentField.  So basically my final result should look like this:

Child table:

```
ChildKey     ChildField
-------------------
 c1           ccc
 c2           aaa
 c3           bbb
```

Comment: In general, you should tell us which version of which database server you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you;

```
UPDATE ChildTable ct SET ct.ChildField = 
    (SELECT MAX(ParentField) FROM ParentTable pt 
    INNER JOIN RelationshipTable rt ON rt.ParentKey=pt.ParentKey 
    WHERE rt.ChildKey=ct.ChildKey)
WHERE ct.ChildField IS NULL
```

If you have an empty `ChieldField` as an empty string rather than `NULL`, try

```
UPDATE ChildTable ct SET ct.ChildField = 
    ISNULL((SELECT MAX(ParentField) FROM ParentTable pt 
    INNER JOIN RelationshipTable rt ON rt.ParentKey=pt.ParentKey 
    WHERE rt.ChildKey=ct.ChildKey),'')
WHERE ct.ChildField=''
```

Comment: I see you use Transact-SQL, this is for MySQL so maybe it won't work.

Comment: @apartridge . . . You can easily make this t-sql compatible by removing the `order by . . . limit 1`.  If you want to guarantee only one result, then change the `select` to `select max(ParentField)`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I assumed that there is the possibility of multiple identical ChildKey in the relationship table.

Comment: I"m getting the following error whenever I try to run the SQL:

SQL Error: ORA-01407: cannot update ("AWDPOWNER"."W00U999S"."INXFLD01") to NULL
01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"

Comment: So i guess your field `ChildField` cannot be `NULL`? You can try to wrap the result from the subquery with `ISNULL`. Updated first answer.

Comment: This is not how to join tables in an update, read the answer from @Greg

Answer (score 2):

Even without a foreign key, you can still join the two tables together to do the update:

```
update      child
set         childfield = parent.parentfield
from        child
inner join  Relationship on Relationship.ChildKey = Child.ChildKey
INNER JOIN  Parent on PArent.ParentKey = Relationship.ParentKey
WHERE       Child.ChildField IS NULL
```

This should work in Microsoft SQL Server. Pretty sure it will work elsewhere as well